# Prevent Caching of Div Background Image?

Tags: javascript, css, caching

I have the following code in place for showing user avatar thumbnails:

```
<div id="custom_avatar" style="background-image: url('image.php?user={UserID}&amp;type=thumb');" alt="Avatar"></div>
```

This unfortunately keeps the images in cache for a long time (weeks).

If I add "&querystring=test" to the end of the above URL, it grabs the most recent image! The problem is that people change their avatars all the time, so I can't just keep changing the query string.

Is there a way I can append a query string with random number (or current timestamp) on the image, so it always grabs a fresh copy? We don't have very much traffic, so I'm not worried about offload.

I tried adding this JavaScript, but it does not work:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date(); 
    document.getElementById("custom_avatar").style.backgroundImage="url('image.php?user={UserID}&amp;type=thumb&amp;unique=" + d.getTime() + "')";
</script>
```

Comment: because it should not be `&amp;` Change it to just `&`

Comment: I've changed to just & but it still does not refresh. Thanks!

Comment: I'm no expert with query caching, but could you not have the entire page send a No Cache request: <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />

Comment: Randomly generating a `filename.png?randomstuff` is the only way I know of